# Why is Visual Studio 2017 messing up my py file?

Tags: python, indentation

Until now I have programmed python3 using pythons IDLE where I can edit my code and run it from command line without problems.

Now I decided to use Visual Studio 2017 as my IDE.

I have created a Visual Studio python project from my existing code.

The program runs fine if I just let it run without changes.

But every time I enter a new line of code into my program, Visual studio messes up everything.

For example I add the following function:

```
def test():
    pass
```

Now visual studio marks it red an gives error for the first line: "unexpected token ''" and for the second line: "unexpected ident".
Now the functions beneath also get marked red. All errors seems to be about unexpected tokens and unexpected ident.

This happens regardless where I change the code in the whole .py file. It happens in function already existing or outside funtion. And it also happens if I just copy and paste n new line of code.

The code and the idents are correct as far as I can check it! I also have tried to mark the whole code and then used "Edit -> Advanced -> Untabify Selected Lines".
So I guess idents should now be correct.

The workaround for now is also very strange: I do need to select the whole code with ctrl-a, copy it with ctrl-c, delete the whole code and then paste it again with ctrl-v.
Now the code looks exactly as before, but VS errors are gone. I can let the programm run without problems.

How can I avoid this workaround? Its driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be found here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/4835

Just replace every "TODO" appearance in your code with "TO DO", also in the comments of course.

Unbelievable but true!